# When to use servlet request and response exactly?

Tags: java, servlets

While creating a servlet, i get confused between request and response methods.
What should be my perspective while writing a servlet, should i view the servlet and think as servlet is making its request and response or do the same from the client side.

For example,
Why is response.getWriter() from response side?

Similarly for certain response and request methods.

Comment: Your Servlet is part of a server. It receives requests and sends responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't get confused.

The request is coming from the client side.

The response is what the servlet going to send to the client side.

So you will need to write something to response most of the time. This is  where you get a writer object. So `response.getWriter()` gives you the writer object.

The servlet does not itself create the response and request objects. The container creates them and forwards these objects to the matching servlet based on the client's http request.